# Irrelevant components rerendering when switching between light and dark modes in Class component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, memoization

Switching between dark and light modes in my application rerenders other parts of the page that have nothing to do with the themes switching. I should also note that I am using React and redux saga to watch for the theme. Not sure if this information is relevant but just putting it out there. When I switch from light to dark or vice versa, some parts of the page does a rerender, which resets some values. For example, my application is a crypto application and I am using a helper file that injects the bitcoin symbol in front of bitcoin values instead of the $ sign, which was the default. Now after switching the theme, the bitcoin symbol changes to the $ sign instead of the bitcoin symbol. My guess is that the util/library/file used to do the symbol check does not run again after the theme switch

Comment: This most likely doesn't have anything to do with the saga. What components are selecting on `state.user` and `state.user.preferences` ? Those would all need to re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do with the Redux-Saga. This is how React works. When some update happens to props or state, it will start to re-render all the necessary components. That doesn’t mean it causes Real DOM to Redraw. It just updates VDOM.

> Updating the VDOM doesn't necessarily trigger an update of the real DOM.

If you want to prevent the re-rendering of a specific component, you can use **Pure Components** in React.